# Insert text in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to make a barplot in `R` using `ggplot2`. I want to put the text `D=3` in the graph located in the middle of x axis and in y=0.55, but I don´t know how. I've been looking for a solution but I have not found anything.

Thanks for help[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future reference, it's much easier for us to help you when you provide some sample data, or use Rs readily available data sets such as `mtcars` or `iris`. But great to see that you have come up with a solution by yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer in a blog. I just needed to use this code `geom_text(data = NULL, x = 3.5, y = 0.55, label = "D=3", size=10)` and I got next graph. I hope it can be useful for any of you. [image]

Comment: That's not a good solution. geom_text has the behaviour that it draws "something" for each row. This is the reason why your font seems so "bold" - because you have several 'D=3' plotted on top on one another. That is not really what you want, as it is difficult to really control. Use `annotate(geom = 'text', x = 3.5, y = 0.55, label = 'D = 3')` instead. Note, the font size in geom_text is *not* the font size in points. If you want the font size in points, multiply with 5/14

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tjebo. In fact the size of the text is bigger (and seems to be bold) because it was specified in the code, and I'm not worried about `geom_text` repeating text beacuse it was avoided by using `data=NULL`. However, your code is also useful, and I know it could help in other situations.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are not right - the behaviour is not avoided using data = NULL. I've tried it to double check. ggplot is drawing it multiple times. Save the plot as a pdf and open it in a pdf editor (e.g. illustrator) and you will see.